# Keeping production configuration files hidden from developers

Tags: git, security, heroku

I got to the part of my system evolution that I got some files that contains credentials for sensitive data, I'm using git based deployment via heroku, and would like to keep doing that easy way.

How can I remove a few configuration lines from one branch, keep it on the other and make sure it stays there when merge occur?

What the best practive here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sensitive data should not be in source control - you should use Heroku config variables which will then be exposed as environment variables in your application. Read more on the Heroku site at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 0):

I you were a Microsoft.NET shop you could use config file includes:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="HerokuSpecificConfigFile.config" />
```

Your publish profile transformation than would replace development connection strings with the include line above. This would allow you to keep `HerokuSpecificConfigFile.config` in your deployment remote only.